# Torah Learning Time Calculator

Tags: books-generally, torah-study, time

I am looking for something that will take the sefer I want to learn, and the amount of time/days I want to complete it in and tell me the average amount I need to learn a day. It doesn't have to be precisely that, but something of the sort that will help me decide a pace for learning. Good answers will have information/links to resources as well as a brief descriptions of the resources.

Comment: Hard question to answer as there are quick and slow readers, quick and slow understanders, and many other variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an excellent website for such calculations [here](http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=56&seriesid=9). It is customizable based on the sefer and review schedule of your preference. It is a little complicated, but provides example entries to help you figure out how to use it. Also, there are links on the side of that webpage leading to versions of the calculator specific to daf yomi/ amud yomi/ tanach/ mishnayos/ rambam/ halacha.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, jake. I just used it to setup a two-year Nach learning program.

Comment: @Tzvi and anyone else interested, if the purpose is for Nach, also check out the month-by-month system devised by Avi Kadish [here](https://sites.google.com/site/kadish67/nakh-en).